# CollectionViewSource.Filter is not raised with several CVS for the same collection in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

I am sharing a the same collection of items among several view models in a DataGrid. When one item on this shared list is selected, I need it to disappear from the list of the others items.

Here are the different view models used:

### ParentViewModel.cs

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<SharedItemViewModel> _sharedItems;

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        // Shared items
        _sharedItems = new ObservableCollection<SharedItemViewModel>
        {
            new SharedItemViewModel { Visible = true },
            new SharedItemViewModel { Visible = true }
        };
        
        this.Children = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>
        {
            // Each child references the same list
            new ChildViewModel(_sharedItems),
            new ChildViewModel(_sharedItems)
        }
    }
    
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Children { get; }
}
```

### SharedItemViewModel.cs

```
public class SharedItemViewModel
{
    private bool _visible;
    
    public bool Visible
    {
        get => _visible;
        set => this.UpdateProperty(ref _visible, value); // Raises the PropertyChanged event properly
    }
}
```

### ChildViewModel.cs

```
public class ChildViewModel
{
    private SharedItemViewModel _selectedItem;

    public ChildViewModel(ObservableCollection<SharedItemViewModel> sharedItems)
    {
        this.Items = sharedItems;
    }
    
    public ObservableCollection<SharedItemViewModel> Items { get; }
    
    public SharedItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set 
        {
            if(_selectedItem != value)
            {
                // Set the old item visible again
                if (_selectedItem != null)
                {
                    _selectedItem.Visible = true;
                }
                
                _selectedItem = value;
                
                // Set the new item not visible
                if (value != null)
                {
                    _selectedItem.Visible = false;
                }
                
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To do so, I am trying to use a different `CollectionViewSource` for each row:

### MyView.xaml

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <CollectionViewSource 
                                                    x:Key="LocalItems"
                                                    Source="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                                    Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"
                                                    IsLiveFilteringRequested="True">
                                <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
                                    <sys:String>Visible</sys:String>
                                </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
                            </CollectionViewSource>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        
                        <ComboBox 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalItems}}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### MyView.xaml.cs

```
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Accepted = [..]; // Some work here to do to decide whether the item should be visible
}
```

When I run the application, the shared items are well bound to the comboboxes. When I select one item in one combobox, the `Visible` property is well set and the `PropertyChanged` event is well raised.

My issue is that I never (neither at loading nor when the `Visible` property changed) hit the `Filter` handler in my code-behind (tested with a breakpoint).

**Do you know what is wrong with this code?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the event isn't raised but you could either filter the `Items` source collection directly, or you could try to set the `Filter` property of the view when the `Grid` in the `CellTemplate` is loaded:

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = (Grid)sender;
    CollectionViewSource cvs = grid.Resources["LocalItems"] as CollectionViewSource;
    if (cvs != null)
        cvs.View.Filter = (s) => true; //your filtering logic here...
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="LocalItems">
        ...
```

Comment: The filter event is raised with this solution, it's a progress ! But I cannot perform my filtering logic only with the `SharedItemViewModel`. I also need to access the `ChildViewModel` (It's not as simple as my `Visible` property in my exemple :s).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround but I will not mark it as an answer since it "breaks" a little bit the MVVM pattern by adding a dependency to `WindowsBase` into my ViewModel.

The solution consists in building the `CollectionViewSource` in the `ChildViewModel`:

```
public class ChildViewModel
{
    private SharedItemViewModel _selectedItem;

    public ChildViewModel(ObservableCollection<SharedItemViewModel> sharedItems)
    {
        var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
        cvs.Source = sharedItems;
        cvs.IsLiveFilteringRequested = true;
        cvs.LiveFilteringProperties.Add(nameof(SharedItemViewModel.Visible));
        cvs.View.Filter = this.Filter;

        this.Items = cvs.View;
    }
    
    public ICollectionView Items { get; }
    
    public SharedItemViewModel SelectedItem {..}
    
    private bool Filter(object obj)
    {
        var vm = obj as SharedItemViewModel;
        
        return vm.Visible;
    }
}
```